# AWS Lambda - runs every minute without cloud-watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function in AWS Lambda that is executed every minute without any trigger. Is there anything I am missing? I do not have any time loop in my function.

[image]

Comment: go into the lambda console to see if there are any triggers. If not, can you verify there isnt an external service on a cron that is invoking lambda?

Comment: It was very strange. I deleted all rules but after I reinstated two tests I did check with `aws events list-rule-names-by-target --target-arn` and it had the listed. I need to now wait and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting to print/log the lambda event.
Sometimes, you can identify the triggering service only based on the event!

Disclosure: I work for Lumigo, and that's how we do it :-)